# Retrofit v2.4.0 is not sending the If-Modified-Since header

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, okhttp

This may be a very basic question, but I've ran out of ideas. 
Retrofit v2.4.0 is not sending the *If-Modified-Since* header, as a result caching is not working.

I'm polling the server several times a day to see if is there any updated data, hence the need for *If-Modified-Since* header. (push notifications may be implemented in a new release)

Based on this article, the setup is extremely easy: https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-activate-response-caching-etag-last-modified

I've read several related articles, but those were focused on the use-cases when the server's implementation was either inaccessible or it didn't send the headers. This is not my case. Those suggested the usage of `networkInterceptors()`. As the correct response headers are sent, I shouldn't need an interceptor (I guess).

Theoretically it should work.

Based on the response headers, it looks like that the server is correctly configured.

Here's the code:

```
HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.HEADERS);

Cache cache = new Cache(getApplication().getCacheDir(), 30 * 1024 * 1024);

httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .cache(cache)
    .addInterceptor(logging)
    .build();

retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl("http://someserver:8080/")
    .callbackExecutor(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor())
    .client(httpClient)
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .build();
```

Logs:

> D/OkHttp: --> GET http://someserver:8080/model/modelId http/1.1  
>   D/OkHttp: --> END GET
>
> <-- 200 OK http://someserver:8080/model/modelId (23ms) 
>   D/OkHttp: Cache-Control: private 
>  D/OkHttp: Content-Length:
>   3240854 
>  D/OkHttp: Content-Type: application/octet-stream 
>   D/OkHttp: Last-Modified: Mon, 14 May 2018 07:22:25 GMT 
>   D/OkHttp: Date: Mon, 14 May 2018 09:03:50 GMT 
>  D/OkHttp: <-- END
>   HTTP

Please let me know what am I doing wrong.

Comment: If you look at the Troubleshooting section of [this](https://android.jlelse.eu/reducing-your-networking-footprint-with-okhttp-etags-and-if-modified-since-b598b8dd81a1) article it looks like the Cache-Control header isn't setup correctly. It should be "Cache-Control: private, must-revalidate". Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Yup, this solved the issue :-)
Can you please post a comment so I can accept it?

Comment: I've posted my answer, please accept it @Robby

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your server's cache configuration is incorrect. If you look at [this article's](https://android.jlelse.eu/reducing-your-networking-footprint-with-okhttp-etags-and-if-modified-since-b598b8dd81a1) Troubleshooting section you'll notice that it needs to be `Cache-Control: private, must-revalidate`.